# Rails Country_select can't save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I am having trouble integrating this select country plug in (https://github.com/scudco/country_select_test) into my test application. I installed it and put it into my database. It shows up when I type my id into the rails console but it always comes up as nil. Here is my view.haml:

```
.form-group
        = f.input :country_code, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control"
      .form-group
        = f.input :address, autofocus: false, :class => "form-control"
```

Here is the migration I recently made:

```
class AddCountryCodeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
   add_column :users, :country_code, :string
  end
end
```

The output of my console:

```
updated_at: "2015-08-07 15:29:26", address: " ", country_code: nil>
```

I have nothing about the :country_code in my users.rb file. I used to have the assert country_code in their but it didn't change anything when I took it out. Thank you to everyone who helps me out. I'm still a noob at ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably miss to allow the `:country_code` param in your `UsersController` due to strong_parameters

In your controller you should have something like

```
def users_params
  params.require(:user).permit(...)
end
```

You need to ensure, in the `permit` method, that `:country_code` is called too. For example:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:country_code, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't add it to my controller. Thanks a lot! You're awesome : )

Comment: Thanks ;) it happened to me various times and I have always lost a lot of time on it. I hope I saved you some time ;)